# Translation of an Hebrew phrase

Tags: hebrew

What does "shalom shalom wekhol Tuv" mean? This was said at the closing of an email. I have researched on the internet for an explanation and I could not find an answer. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Much peace and goodness. Welcome to this website!

Comment: *vekhol tuv. Also, welcome to Mi Yodeya!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

שלום שלום, וכל טוב

"shalom shalom wekhol Tuv"

**Peace, Peace, and all the best.**

Comment: This isn't the most literal of translations.

Comment: The OP didn't ask for a literal translation. It asked for a translation of a phrase used in a certain setting. As a multi-lingual person, I think that my translation is the most accurate one, in this context.

Comment: I didn't downvote